# MongoDB c# Update.PushWrapped, how use it?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How i can push an item in an Array?
I see that i can insert only basic value (String, Int32, Int64, Boolean) but i can't insert into an array an INSTANCE of custom class.

```
//in this way, it work:
var myPlayer = new i_Player();
this.mongo_collection.FindAndModify(
Query.EQ("_id",ID),
SortBy.Ascending("_id"),
Update.PushWrapped<i_Player>("_player", myPlayer),
true
);

// in this way, don't work because i_Player is not an BsonValue but is my CLASS!
var myPlayer = new i_Player();
this.mongo_collection.FindAndModify(
Query.EQ("_id",ID),
SortBy.Ascending("_id"),
Update.Push("_player", myPlayer),
true
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PushWrapped` coming with driver 1.0 (seems) and simply convert your class to `BsonDocument`:

```
Update.PushWrapped<i_Player>("_player", myPlayer);
```

In case if you using `Update.Push` you need to do it manually:

```
Update.Push("_player", myPlayer.ToBsonDocument());
```

I am using `ToBsonDocument()` to convert some class object to `BsonValue`.

So, just choose what do you like more..